# How do I select the min from a function in SQL?

Tags: sql, datediff, min

I want to take the difference between my date column and the current date, find the minimum and store it in a variable.

I have:

```
DECLARE @DAY AS INTEGER;
SET @DAY = 
    SELECT MIN (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, date_col, GETDATE())
        FROM tb1);
```

but the min function isn't accepting the select and the datediff function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT MIN (DATEDIFF(DAY, date_col, GETDATE()))
FROM tb1
```

You don't need the nested select.

Comment: Thank you, the problem I had with doing it without nesting was that I was putting the end parenthesis after the FROM. You helped me a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```
select @day = min(DateDiff(DAY,date_col,GetDate())) from tbl
```